# How do I pluralize or singularize multiple nouns?

Tags: node.js, nlp, nlp-compromise

I'm using the excellent `nlp-compromise` module for NLP.

I'm stuck at what should be a rather straightforward process: pluralizing or singularizing all nouns.

So far, I've got this:

```
let a = nlp("apples, oranges, pears")
a.nouns().toSingular()
a.out("text")
```

However, this returns

> apple, oranges, pears

Whilst what I really want is

> apple, orange, pear

[Runkit here](https://runkit.com/hueyy/58c35cd7dd18b30014a0953e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've poured over the [limited documentation](https://nlp-expo.firebaseapp.com/docs) without much success. However, I've stumbled upon a workaround of sorts:

```
a.match("#Noun").nouns().toSingular()
```

This appears to match all the nouns, instead of just the first one, returning

> apple, orange, pear

[Runkit here](https://runkit.com/hueyy/58c35d82dd18b30014a09561)

Comment: yeah! been workin on the docs. Things are considerably better, i think, now.

Answer (score 1):

this was a bug that just got fixed in `v10.6.0`.

https://runkit.com/spencermountain/595e48ab230e340012e1d314

(especially) with the commas, they are indeed three nouns, which all now inflect individually.

thanks for your help.